# Series, and Sequences $a_n = \frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Is the following sequence convergent?
>   $$a_n = \frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!}$$

I have this sequence to calculate whether it converges or not, as well as where does it converge and I was wondering if the way I proceeded with the problem was optimal.

I have to admit I don't fully grasp the factorial precalculus methods, and would be open to suggestions.  I am getting the problem from the James Stewart *Essential Calculus Early Transcendentals 2nd Edition*.

This is the way I did the problem, and I am wondering

A. if its right, and

B. Are there resources I could have to better tackle factorials in my calculus problems.

\begin{align}
           a_n&= \frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!} \\
           \lim_\limits{n \to \infty}(a_n)&=\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}(\frac{\frac{(2n)!}{2n}}{(2n+1)(2n)!})\\
            &= \lim_\limits{n \to \infty} (\frac{1}{2n(2n+1)}) = 0
\end{align}
That is the answer in the back of the book, but I wonder if my process was right. Thank you.

Comment: The process is correct. Arguably it is not the most "natural" (but this is really subjective and shouldn't bother you) I would do something like $$\frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!} = \frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)(2n)(2n-1)!} = \frac{1}{2n(2n+1)}$$

Comment: Are you supposed to check if the sequence converges or the corresponding series? Your subject seems to mention series...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your process is correct. Usually, you would simply notice that $(2n+1)!=(2n-1)! (2n)(2n+1)$ (in the same way that $8!=6!\times 7\times8$) so 
$$
\frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!}=\frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n-1)! (2n)(2n+1)}=\frac{1}{(2n)(2n+1)}.
$$